# Reference style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I write a thesis and according to my university rules, the style of the references should be as in the below image:

[image]

I tried many styles, but could not find the right style as in the above image, how can I build a custom style or modify an existing style to meet the previous style?

**Edit**
I use `natbib` with these options

```
\usepackage[numbers,square,authoryear,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

and the current style is `abbrvnat`

the required style is:

1. **For papers:** 
   last name first name middle name,"title of paper", journal name, volume , pages, year.
2. **For thesis or dissertations:** 
   last name first name middle name,"title of thesis or dissertation", type of the thesis (*i.e.* **M.Sc** or **Ph.D.**), department , university name, year.
3. **For books:** 
   last name first name middle name,"title of book (underline)", edition, publisher, year.

   - the first and middle names written in abbreviation.
   - the year written between parentheses.
   - if there is an URL then it would be embed in journal name, publisher or in university name.

this is a simple of the `.bib` file,

```
 @Book{harnoy,
  title     = {Bearing design in machinery},
  publisher = {Marcel Dekker},
  year      = {2003},
  author    = {Harnoy, Avraham},
  place     = {New York},
}

@PhdThesis{Qiu,
  author = {Zhi Ling Qiu},
  title  = {A theoritical and Experimental Study on the Caharacteristics of Journal Bearings},
  school = {Department of Mechanical Engineering University of Wollongong},
  year   = {1995},
  type   = {Doctor of Philosophy thesis},
}

@article{yang,
  doi = {10.1177/1350650111431526},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/1350650111431526},
  year  = {2012},
  month = {jan},
  publisher = {{SAGE} Publications},
  volume = {226},
  number = {4},
  pages = {328--339},
  author = {W. Weimin and Y. Lihua and W. Tiejun and Y. Lie},
  title = {Nonlinear dynamic coefficients prediction of journal bearings using partial derivative method},
  journal = {Proceedings of the Institution of Mechanical Engineers,  Part  J: Journal of Engineering Tribology}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a preference for a specific bibliography package (`biblatex` vs. `natbib`/`cite`/other BibTeX-packages)? How do in-text citations look like? Do you have anything to start from, so we don't have to start from scratch. You might also want to give us some `.bib` items to play around with. (An [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/) would be great.) Please note also that on this page questions such as "write this style for me" are often too broad, it is often more useful to focus on specific properties of the style (many aspects of your style will have been dealt with before).

Comment: Note that the style features some (I'd say unusual) peculiarities: amongst them that the year is at the very end of the entry - even after the page number, and that there can be a comma before the brackets around the year. Underlining an unusual design choice since we don't use typewriters any more.

Comment: Note also that the style is anything but consistent in the way page ranges are indicated. For instance, in the entries by Chung and Yafai and by Hadley, a simple `-` ("dash", "hyphen") is used as the connector. In other entries, such as those by El-Ayachi et al. and by Ghazanfarian and Abbassi, the character that's in use looks like either an en-dash (which would be appropriate) or a math-minus sign (which would *not* be appropriate). Do you want to replicate these inconsistencies? If not, which stylistic choice should be made?

Comment: @moewe  I know it is not a standard style but I must follow the university instructions, I edit the question please take a look.

Comment: @Mico - No I don'y,  I used `abbrvnat`, but it didn't give what I need, I added the required style to the equation, please take a look of the edited part.

Comment: Please debug the formatting instructions some more. For example, for articles published in journals, should there really be no comma between (a) the last name and (b) the first and middle names? Conversely, should there indeed be a comma between the first and middle names for book-type items? Should first and middle names be written out in fully or truncated? Should there be no "and" connector between the next-to-last and last author in a list of authors? What about unpublished papers and papers circulated in a working paper series (or discussion paper series) of some institution?

Comment: I've voted to close this posting as a duplicate; please see the associated link to the previous question. The main answer there -- which also applies to your new question -- is to run the `makebst` utility, which is part of the [custom-bib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/custom-bib/) package. With this utility, you can create your own completely tailored bst file which, as a bonus, will work very well with the `natbib` citation management package.

Comment: @Mico - At first the first and middle names are written in truncated form, the comma used to separate the co-authors list and should be "and" connector between the next to last author in a list of authors, second there should not be comma `,` between the names (I will update the question), the comma is used to separate between the different kinds of the reference parts. And third, perhaps if you can show me how to do the above 3-types then I can modify the other different types.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool - Please familiarize yourself with the `makebst` utility that's mentioned by Alan Munn in the answer he provided in the earlier posting. You will get the bst file you really need *must faster* that way.

Comment: @Mico - Thanks a lot, could you put the URL of the answer so I can check it.

Comment: @MuhammadAbdulrasool - Just click on the line below **This question already has an answer here:**, near the very top of this posting.